# Python transforming one dimensional array into two dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a list

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

I want to convert this as [[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8]] in python. Can somebody help me with this

Comment: What kind of transformation do you want to apply? Do you just want to split it in the middle?

Comment: Is there a way to split it based on a user input?? if he says 4 then the 1d array is split into 2x4. or if he says 2 then there will be a 2d array of dimension 4x2??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To take an input:

```
def chunks(l, n):
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
while 1:
    try:
        size = int(raw_input('What size? ')) # Or input() if python 3.x
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Numbers only please"

print chunks(yourlist, size)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]] # Assuming 2 was the input
```

Or even:

```
>>> zip(*[iter(l)]*size) # Assuming 2 was the input
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Comment: Why isnt "chunks" in standard library? I need it so often...

Answer (score 4):

You can use  `itertools.islice`:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
def solve(lis, n):
     it = iter(lis)
     return [list(islice(it,n)) for _ in xrange(len(lis)/n)]
... 
>>> solve(range(1,9),4)
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
>>> solve(range(1,9),2)
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 4):

There's also the numpy way (if your list is a uniform list of numbers or strings, etc.).

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array(lst)
nslices = 4
a.reshape((nslices, -1))
```