# How to get multiprocessing.Pool().starmap() to return iterable

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Im trying to construct a dataframe from the inputs of a function as well as the output. Previously I was using for loops

```
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        k = func(i, j)
        (Place i, j, k into dataframe)
```

However the range was quite big so I tried to speed it up with multiprocessing.Pool()

```
with mp.Pool() as pool:
    result = pool.starmap(func, ((i, j) for j in range(y) for i in range(x))
    (Place result into dataframe)
```

However with pool I no longer have access to i and j as they are merely inputs into the function

I tried to get the function to return the inputs but that doesn't really make sense as the number of for loops increases, hence how to get the iterables passed into starmap?

Comment: what's the role of `i, j` for your dataframe?

Comment: This is actually trying to do optimisation and i, j are the inputs so to find most optimal case will need to know inputs

Comment: I'm not asking about optimisation, I'm asking HOW do you place those `i, j` in the dataframe, cause the way you do that can be not efficient in terms of dataframe processing

Comment: They will have their individual column

Comment: starmap returns the result in the order they were submitted, so after you get the results you can run the same loop but this time without needing to call `func`. Honestly, this is not a good task for multiprocessing, unless the `func` calls take a lot of time I doubt you will see any improvement in performance

Comment: In my case func really does take a lot of time, but what would you then recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `starmap` version and normal version are not equivalent. When using multiple loops in a generator expression, the outer loop comes first. So the call should rather be:

```
result = pool.starmap(func, ((i, j) for i in range(x) for j in range(y)))
```

Coming back to the question, like I mentioned in the comments, starmap returns the task results in the same order they were submitted. So considering that the only thing you unwanted to parallelize were the `func` calls, you can simply append all the results in one list, chunk it based on the value of `y` (the number of columns), and run another set of `for` loops outside the pool to get the value of `i`, `j`, and return value of `func` at the same time. Example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def func(i, j):
    return f"{i}{j}"


# https://stackoverflow.com/a/17483656/16310741
def chunks(l, n):
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = 3
    y = 4

    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        # ['00', '01', '02', '03', '10', '11', '12', '13', '20', '21', '22', '23']
        result = pool.starmap(func, ((i, j) for i in range(x) for j in range(y)))

        # [['00', '01', '02', '03'], ['10', '11', '12', '13'], ['20', '21', '22', '23']]
        result = chunks(result, y)  

        for i in range(x):
            for j in range(y):
                curr_result = result[i][j]
                print(i, j, curr_result)
                # Do something with i, j, and curr_result
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Just a slight edit I think its faster to use np.reshape instead of chunks